# How to set background image on empty div with responsive css?

Tags: html, css, compass-sass

I have set below code for background image on empty div but it is not responsive. I don't want to set fixed height. is there any other way to do so?

```
.flexslider .slides .page-hero {
    background-position: 50% 0%;
    background-image: url('https://simu.danoneactivia.co.uk/sites/EN_UK/files/carousel/final-Frontpage-Activia-banner.jpg');
}
.front .page-hero {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
.page-hero {
    background-color: #008b3c;
}
.page-hero {
    height: 535px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

Comment: use `background-size : cover;`

Comment: it would be better to have visual example (if possible) such as using fiddle etc

Comment: Use `background-size:100% 100%;`

Comment: I solved issue using  background-size: 100% auto; padding-top: 39.6%; and removed height attribute.